# Embedding code in an inline data structure definition

Tags: perl, reference

**PROBLEM:**
I have a data structure, similar to the following:

```
$foo = [
    {
        bar => "baz",
    },
];
```

I want to embed code within this data structure to add another hashref into `foo`'s list, so that the end result will be this:

```
$foo = [
    {
        bar => "baz",
    },
    {
        new => "new",
    },
];
```

**POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS:**

**1:** My initial instinct was to use `eval`

```
$foo = [
    {
        bar => "baz",
    },
    eval { return {
        new => "new",
    }},
];
```

**2:** @Sputnik pointed me towards [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References).  The "Making References->4" section helped me come up with another possible solution

```
$foo = [
    {
        bar => "baz",
    },
    &{ sub{ return {
        new => "new",
    }}},
];
```

**QUESTIONS:**
    1.  Are these two solutions equivalent?
    2.  If they are not equivalent, what are the benefits and drawbacks of each?
    3.  Are there any other solutions?
    4.  If there are other solutions, what are their benefits and drawbacks compared to the solutions presented above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [`do BLOCK`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) is for:

```
$foo = [
    {
        bar => "baz",
    },
    do {
        +{
            new => "new",
         },
    },
];
```

For the record, the difference between the solutions is:

- `do BLOCK` only takes a block and turns it into an expression.  It's the fastest/cheapest solution and has the fewest side-effects.
- `eval BLOCK` catches any exceptions thrown by the block and throws them away.  It's generally not safe to use unless you're going to be checking for exceptions afterward.
- `sub { CODE }->()` is a true code ref; as a consequence, it's more expensive (a full function call vs. a block) and of course is more code.
- `&{sub { CODE }}()` is the same as the previous item; it's more expensive and harder to read.  In general, stacked, nested delimiters like this tend to take more effort to decode.
- `&{sub { CODE }}` is a function call, but unlike the previous two it does not set up new arguments.  Instead, `@_` inside `CODE` is still set to the caller's arguments.  This allows you to access your arguments inside the expression if you haven't named them, but it's best avoided since `&foo` in general is a very dangerous way to call functions.

Elaboration on the last point: `&foo` looks like it calls `foo` with no arguments.  It does not.  Instead, it calls `foo` while leaving `@_` aliased to the *caller's* arguments.  That means if `foo` uses a standard pattern to un-pack its function arguments:

```
sub foo {
    my $arg1 = shift;
    my $arg2 = shift;
    ...
}
```

and the caller access its arguments through `@_`:

```
sub bar {
    print $_[0], "\n";
    &foo;
    print $_[0], "\n";
}
```

the call to `foo` modifies `bar`'s arguments, so this function prints the first *and third* arguments to `bar` (assuming `foo` has only two arguments).

So never use `&foo` to call a function; it's always worth it to be clear:

```
foo();
```

or

```
foo(\@_);
```

if you *want* `foo` to modify your arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Eval is evil, the good way is :

```
push @{ $array_ref }, { new => "new" };
```

I think you should read docs about *references* :

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html

**DEMO**:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $foo = [
    {
        bar => "baz",
    },
];

push @{ $foo }, { new => "new" };

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $foo;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'bar' => 'baz'
          },
          {
            'new' => 'new'
          }
        ];
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  Perhaps I was not clear enough in my initial question (I should have included a code example of how I was thinking of using eval), but I did specify `"I want to embed code within this data structure"`, and your solution with `push` does not help me do this.  That being said, the documents were helpful.  Specifically, [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) mentions in `Making References->4` that sub references are treated similarly to eval.  I would appreciate your input based on my new edits.

Comment: Have you tested with Data::Dumper ? I get **exactly** the needed output. What is the point to not using `push` ?

Comment: Yes, it will result in my required output.  However, it does not satisfy my *esential* requirement that the code be embedded within the data structure itself.  This requirement is the entire reason I'm asking this question- I already know how to use `push`  =)